# r - Nesting multiple Functions via Apply

Tags: r, nested, apply

I would like to find the number of missing values in a data set similar to mtcars using is.na and sum.

Here is my code:

```
x <- apply(mtcars, 2, is.na)
y <- apply(x, 2, sum)
```

However this is ugly.  Is their a way to do the equivalent of:

```
z <- apply(mtcars, 2, sum(is.na))
```

Comment: Why not `colSums(is.na(mtcars))`

Comment: @akrun in the event that I need to nest multiple functions in a generic 'apply()' style is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you try the solution posted below

Comment: I think you want to use `compose` as in the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lamdba expression (either `function(x)` or the shorthand (`\(x)` from `R 4.1.0`)

```
apply(mtcars, 2, \(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

It may be also possible to do this with the vectorized `colSums` after converting the data.frame to logical `matrix` (`is.na` - as `methods('is.na')` also includes a data.frame specific method)

```
colSums(is.na(mtcars))
  mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

---

Probably, the OP wanted to [`compose`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/compose) multiple functions

```
library(purrr)
apply(mtcars, 2, compose(sum, is.na))
 mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

By default the `.dir` is "backward".  We can override, it by specifying

```
apply(mtcars, 2, compose(is.na, sum, .dir = "forward"))
   mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: I like @ThomasIsCoding 's answer for its simplicity, your response is encyclopedic.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `apply`, you can try this

```
apply(is.na(mtcars), 2, sum)
```

However, [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67993443/12158757) has provided a more efficient approach to achieve the same goal, highly recommended on that!

Comment: Is it possible to nest a third function in this manner?

Comment: @EnglishmanBob Can you show what/how you want to do with a third function?

Comment: I selected @akrun's response due its depth.  However yours succeeds by its simplicity.  If I could selected both I would have.